# Error creating Rails DB using rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm attempting to get my first "hello world" rails example going using the rails' [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on my OSX 10.6.3 box.

When I go to execute the first `rake db:create` command (I'm using mysql) I get:

```
simon@/Users/simon/source/rails/blog/config: rake db:create  (in /Users/simon/source/rails/blog) Couldn't create database for {"reconnect"=>false, "encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"root", "adapter"=>"mysql", "database"=>"blog_development", "pool"=>5, "password"=>nil, "socket"=>"/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

I found plenty of stackoverflow questions addressing this problem with the following advice:

1. Verify that user and password are correct (I'm running w/ no password for root on my dev box)
2. Verify that the socket is correct - I can cat the socket, so I assume it's correct
3. Verify that the user can create a DB (As you can see root can connect and create a this DB no problem)

   simon@/Users/simon/source/rails/blog/config: mysql -uroot -hlocalhost
   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
   Your MySQL connection id is 16
   Server version: 5.1.45 Source distribution

   Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

   mysql> create database blog_development;
   Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

to ensure that this wasn't a charset issue I also tried:

```
mysql> create database foobar CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Note: here is my database.yaml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
#  host: localhost
```

Note that I tried switching socket to localhost with no effect.

Any idea on what might be going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys. Looks like the problem had to do with my install of the mysql gem under OSX.

@tim after I proceeded to the next step and got up and going I got an error on the console, so I did a bit of searching and found this [helpful thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/192550).

After I uninstalled my ruby gems `gem uninstall mysql` I installed the proper mysql gems using this command (from the thread):

`export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" ; gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/opt/local/lib/mysql5 --with-mysql-config=/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_config`

After executing this one I was able to successfully run `rake db:create` and proceed.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It could be a number of things.

- Is your database set for utf8 character set?
- Is the path to the socket correct, since it varies from OS.
- Have you reinstalled the mysql gem? `sudo gem install mysql`
- It might be MySQL, you might want to downgrade the version to 5.0

Other than that, I'm not sure.

Comment: +1 On Ubuntu 16.04 my problem was that my socket `/tmp/mysql.sock` was different than the usual one.
`/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Answer (score 2):

You should post here your database.yml

To make your test better, i would try to create a database UTF-8 to see if your database supports utf-8

```
create database foobar CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Ah, good point. Let me post my database.yaml:

development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
#  host: localhost

Note that I tried switching socket to localhost with no effect.

Good idea on the charset test:


mysql> create database foobar CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

But no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Note I posted above with a better formatted version of the comment

Answer (score 0):

Does the `blog_development` database already exist?

If so, you can just continue to the next step.

Try running `ruby script/server` in the `blog/` directory.

If it doesn't error out, then you should be able to navigate to `localhost:3000` and continue the tutorial from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails.

Leave me a comment if `ruby script/server` errors out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, much appreciated!

After I created the `blog_development` DB manually I was able to start  rails and continue.

I'm a little concerned about the error though, perhaps this means I will have DB connection problems in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue : it was an old mysql gem which was not up to date. Re-installing the mysql gem did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install mysql-server and mysql-client using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

and then some libraries you need to install to make MySQL available to ruby:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby
```

This all solved my problem. Try it !!! :)