# Couldn't create database for Rails app

Tags: ruby, rake, mysql2

When trying to run `rake db:create` or `rake db:setup` I'm getting this error message:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"mydb_dev"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"mydb_test"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
```

I have updated mysql2 and `mysql --version` returns:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.16, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Here's my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: mydb_dev

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: mydb_test

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: mydb_prod
```

Why can't the `rake` command create the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the username and password for your database.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  database: mydb_dev
  username: root
  password:
```

You can learn more about configuring a database in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)

Comment: You might want to try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` that what fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try These configurations:

```
adapter: mysql
database: my_db #name of your database
hostname: 127.0.0.1
username: root #your username
password: # your password
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock #socket parameter is also important
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

Visit this link a similar question ([Error creating Rails DB using rake db:create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672756/error-creating-rails-db-using-rake-dbcreate))